# Ionic permanently removing items from tab list

Tags: list, tabs, ionic-framework

Having an issue with actually clearing out and refreshing list items within a tab view.

A) Within the service, `refresh` sets the return `object` to `null` (verified) calls for fresh data (verified) and returns it to the controller (verified).

B) Within the controller, before `refresh` is called, i validate the length of the previously returned `object`(verified as `length of 6`), then set the object to `null` (verified as null), refresh the data and then validate the returned object (verified as length of 6 again).

My expectation is for the original `list` of 6 items to clear out and be replaced with the `new list` of 6 items. However, the html template `list` of 6 items grows to a `list` of 12, basically duplicating the original list.  Further more, the new `list` of 12 seems to be sorted so the duplicates are listed in order as pairs - which seems like its being sorted.  I don't understand this behavior and I can't figure out how to get displayed list to actually clear out.

```
.controller: 
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
      alert(Object.keys($scope.prods).length) ;  // (6)
      $scope.prods= {} ;
      alert(Object.keys($scope.prods).length) ;  // (0)
      $scope.prods= Prods.refresh();
      alert(Object.keys($scope.prods).length) ;  // (6)
    }

.service:
   refresh: function() {
     prods= [] ;
     getProds() ;
     return prods;
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.  It was my own code.  in "getProds()" I wasn't setting the return object to null, Every time I hit refresh the object was simply adding all the new data onto existing object, and returning back to the controller twice the previous size.